# XL Deploy nesting dictionaries

Tags: automated-deployment, deployit, xl-deploy

I am preparing a an application for deployment using XebiaLabs XL Deploy tool.

It is a .Net Windows Service, with environmental specific configuration (multiple instances across several qa/uat/prod servers) in the app.config.

These config values have been migrated to XL Deploy dictionaries, and the app.config uses placeholders to refer to each required value.

Is there a way to nest dictionaries in XL Deploy? I.e. Dictionary 1 will have a key that has dictionary 2  as it's value?

There is no real information about this in the docs, and not much else to be found about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for this, the solution I came up with was pretty simple - to use grouped keys as values in dictionaries.
For Example:

```
XLD Dictionary 1:
Key    - Value
Key1D1 - Value1
Key2D1 - Value2
Key3D1 - {{Key1D2}} {{Key2D2}} {{Key3D2}} 

XLD Dictionary 2:
Key    - Value
Key1D2 - Value3
Key2D2 - Value4
Key3D2 - Value5
```

Therefore in my config file i can have:

```
Dbconnection = {{Key1D1}}
Dbpassword = {{Key1D2}}
ConfigRules = {{Key1D3}}
```

And use the same config for each version, with all the instance specific ConfigRules set only in XLDeploy dictionaries